# ld returned 1 exit status - error in codeblocks

Tags: c

I've been using codeblocks for a few days now and things worked really good until about an hour ago. I did nothing special just tried to run the code for different parameters. All of a sudden this error pops up:

```
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried to restart codeblocks, I even reinstalled it but it did not work. Also googled but non of the results was of any help. I'm trying to compile the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int IntgApprox(void) {

    int n;
    int N = 10000;
    double x,y;
    double S_n = 0;
    double ErrorTerm = 0;
    double Error = 0;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));            

    for(n = 0; n < N; n++) {                
        x = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;      
        y = 4/(1+x*x);
        S_n = S_n + y;
        ErrorTerm = ErrorTerm + y*y;        
    }

    S_n = S_n/N;
    Error = sqrt(ErrorTerm/n - S_n*S_n)/sqrt(n);
    printf("Integral approx: %f\n", S_n);
    printf("Error term approx: %f\n", Error);
}
```

Note that I get the same error regardless of what I compile.

EDIT: Inserting picture of error.

[image]

Comment: Really? That's the *only* line of error text? There are no lines immediately previous to that that mention one or more missing symbols and/or references (such as the math library function `sqrt` brought in with `-lm`) ??

Comment: Please see my edit. Photo inserted.

Comment: This even happens with an, empty `int main() { return 0; }` ? I ask because the code posted has no `main()`, mandatory for a well-formed C program.

Comment: I use the main in another program where I call `IntgApprox();`

Comment: And yes, it happens with an empty main too :S

Comment: What are the source file names? What is the output from the command line of `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o myexe -lm source1.c source2.c source3.c` ?  (adjust the source names as required and your executable will be `myexe`) Lastly, do not post pictures of output, copy the output and paste your output as text in your question and indent each line by 4-spaces so it formats properly.